# What's the stabilization of the $\infty$-category of $\infty$-categories?

Tags: higher-category-theory, stable-homotopy

$\require{AMScd}$One nice thing about $\infty$-categories is that spaces are themselves $\infty$-categories. What's the analogue for spectra? Presumably this would be the stabilization of the $\infty$-category of $(\infty,1)$-categories, fitting into a cube:

$$
\begin{CD}
ILS_* @>>> \text{Spaces}_* @>>> \text{$(\infty,1)$-Cats}_* @<<< \text{S.M. $(\infty,1)$-Cats}_*\\
@V\simeq VV @V\Sigma^\infty VV @VV\Sigma^\infty V @VV\simeq V\\
\text{ConnSpectra} @>>> \text{Spectra} @>>> ?  @<<< Conn ?
\end{CD}
$$

where the far left/right entries of the top row are respectively symmetric monoidal $(\infty,0/1)$-categories, and the $*$s denote that we have chosen a basepoint. Is this just the $\infty$-category of spectrally enriched categories?

**edit** if this idea doesn't work out, I'm more interested in "What's the analogue for spectra?" than the second question.

Comment: Note that in general you don't have a functor $\Sigma^\infty$ from a category to its stabilization, but only a functor $\Omega^\infty$ going in the other direction ($\Sigma^\infty$ exists when the category is presentable by the adjoint functor theorem). Moreover I don't think that the category of spectrally enriched categories is stable. Interesting question though.

Comment: It feels like loops on some pointed category will be the space of automorphisms of the distinguished object, no? So the stabilization should just be spectra back again... To get a more interesting answer one probably needs to at least consider lax pullbacks in your definition of `loops', but I dunno

Comment: Isn't there some formula for computing stabilizations in terms of presentations?  E.g., if C is a localization of Fun(J,Spaces) at some set of maps, then it's stabilization should be a stable localization of Fun(J,Spectra) at a set of maps, no?  (I'm asking, I don't really know.)  If you compute this on the usual presentation of infty-Cat, you should just get spectra back.

Comment: @CharlesRezk, are you thinking of describing stabilization of a presentable $C$ the localization of $Fun(S^{fin}_{\star}, C)$ at reduced and excisive functors? I think this also only works for presentable categories

Comment: If you are interested in things that are loosely speaking homology theories on categories, one interesting keyword is *noncommutative motives*. (@EldenElmanto the stabilization is always linear functors from $S^{fin}_*$, no presentability assumptions needed)

Comment: @DenisNardin - ah alright good to know!

Comment: @CharlesRezk yes (after inserting 'presentable' and 'accessible' in a few places, at least). This follows from the universal property for maps *out* of a stabilization (that's where I use presentability), together with the universal property of maps out of a localization, right? Alternatively you could probably prove it by hand as in the proof of Higher Algebra 1.4.4.9

Comment: @DylanWilson That's what I thought.  BTW, assuming J is a small category, every localization of Fun(J,Spaces) wrt a *set* of maps is accessible, and conversely all accessible localizations arise in this way.  And all presentible infty-cats are equivalent to ones obtained this way.  So I don't think I have to insert "accessible" or "presentable" anywhere :P

Comment: It might be more interesting to think about stabilizations of slices $\infty\mathrm{Cat}_{/C}$.  I'd guess that the stabilization of $\infty\mathrm{Cat}_{/\Delta^1}$ is something like spans of spectra.

Comment: @CharlesRezk you got me

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In a project in progress with Matan Prasma and Joost Nuiten concerning the abstract cotangent complex formalism we compute the stabilization of the $\infty$-category $\infty\mathrm{Cat}_{/C}$ of $\infty$-categories over a fixed $\infty$-category $C$, and show that it is equivalent to the $\infty$-category of functors $\mathrm{Tw}(C) \to \mathrm{Spectra}$ from the twisted arrow category of $C$ to spectra. In particular, the stabilization of $\infty\mathrm{Cat}$ is equivalent to the $\infty$-category of spectra and the stabilization of $\infty\mathrm{Cat}_{/\Delta^1}$ is equivalent to the $\infty$-category of (co)spans of spectra, as suggested by Charles Rezk in the remarks above.

Another way of phrasing it is to say that the data of a spectrum object in $\infty\mathrm{Cat}_{/C}$ is equivalent to the data of decorating, for each $x,y \in C$, the mapping space $Map_C(x,y)$ with a parametrized spectrum over it, in a way that is suitably functorial in $(x,y) \in C^{op} \times C$. In this language one can phrase and prove the result in the more general setting of enriched categories. We expect to upload this preprint to the arXiv very soon.

**Edit:**

The paper is now on the arXiv and can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.02608).

Comment: Cool!           .................